# Production errors are not logged in the file

Tags: symfony

I am using monolog with this configuration:

```
monolog:
    channels:
        - deprecation # Deprecations are logged in the dedicated "deprecation" channel when it exists

when@dev:
    monolog:
        handlers:
            main:
                type: stream
                path: "%kernel.logs_dir%/%kernel.environment%.log"
                level: debug
                channels: ["!event"]
            # uncomment to get logging in your browser
            # you may have to allow bigger header sizes in your Web server configuration
            #firephp:
            #    type: firephp
            #    level: info
            #chromephp:
            #    type: chromephp
            #    level: info
            console:
                type: console
                process_psr_3_messages: false
                channels: ["!event", "!doctrine", "!console"]

when@test:
    monolog:
        handlers:
            main:
                type: fingers_crossed
                action_level: error
                handler: nested
                excluded_http_codes: [404, 405]
                channels: ["!event"]
            nested:
                type: stream
                path: "%kernel.logs_dir%/%kernel.environment%.log"
                level: debug

when@prod:
    monolog:
        handlers:
            main:
                type: fingers_crossed
                action_level: error
                handler: nested
                excluded_http_codes: [404, 405]
                buffer_size: 50 # How many messages should be saved? Prevent memory leaks
            nested:
                type: stream
                path: "%kernel.logs_dir%/prod.log"
                level: debug
                formatter: monolog.formatter.json
            console:
                type: console
                process_psr_3_messages: false
                channels: ["!event", "!doctrine"]
            deprecation:
                type: stream
                channels: [deprecation]
                path: php://stderr
```

The only thing I actually changed from the default is:

```
path: "%kernel.logs_dir%/prod.log"
```

for the production environment. Have prod.log file but after getting 500 errors the file is empty. Nothing is logged there.
`APP_ENV` is set to `prod` in `.env`.

Comment: I can’t see any issues with your config. Are you sure you have write permissions for the log dir & file?

Comment: Set permissions to 777 just to be sure. Still not logging in it. Strange because I tested in on localhost and there it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Could you please check the web engine error log, what gets logged there on 5xx errors? Also, you could try removing the following **when@prod.monolog.handlers.nested.formatted** so it looks like this:

```
...
when@prod:
    monolog:
        handlers:
            main:
                type: fingers_crossed
                action_level: error
                handler: nested
                excluded_http_codes: [404, 405]
                buffer_size: 50 # How many messages should be saved? Prevent memory leaks
            nested:
                type: stream
                path: "%kernel.logs_dir%/prod.log"
                level: debug
                formatter: monolog.formatter.json
            console:
                type: console
                process_psr_3_messages: false

...
```

Comment: Please, to guide future visitors, point out the main differences and explain what they do.